# ViewRenderable not working properly with VideoView[SceneForm ARCore]

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

Github issue : https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/issues/9

Iam using `ViewRenderable` with this Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/planetInfoCard"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textAlignment="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hi how are you?" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is Button" />

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do you know what to do?" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`TextView`'s and `Button` is coming properly in ARScene, but `VideoView` is moving along with Camera.

[image]

My final goal is to play Video with chroma key.but iam unable to play video also

Comment: VideoView can not be supported by Sceneform 1.0. We're looking into a way support this use case for an upcoming release.

Comment: There is an example that plays an .mp4 video in the official repository:https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/chromakeyvideo

Comment: Yes they added support in 1.4, please see above mentioned GitHub issue

Comment: the above github is not available

Comment: updated link : https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/chromakeyvideo